# iterating through xml node from jquery each

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

my code for html is this

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else {
     xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }

 xmlhttp.open("GET","brands.xml",false);
 xmlhttp.send();
 theXmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
 function fillForm(){
     $(theXmlDoc).find('table[name=brands]').each(function(){
         alert($(this));//doesn't fire when brands.xml contains more than one entry of <table name="brands"> else shows Object object
     });
```

My brands.xml is

```
  <table name="brands">
        <column name="BrandID">1</column>
        <column name="BrandName">AX</column>
        <column name="CompanyInfo">FDC</column>
        <column name="Composition">Cap</column>
 </table>
 <table name="brands">
        <column name="BrandID">2</column>
        <column name="BrandName">UP</column>
        <column name="CompanyInfo">Tor</column>
        <column name="Composition">Asp</column>
 </table>
```

when `brands.xml` contains single entry of `<table name="brands">` alert shows Object object but when i include more than one table name as shown above each is not getting executed.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using jQuery to traverse the XML, but not retrieve it?

Comment: i think jquery has lots of methods to handle stuff,if there is better alternative to access xml from html pls tell me ,and i want to retrieve text but i can only do that once i can loop from xml nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML will need to be wrapped by a single node:

```
<tables>
    <table name="brands">
        <column name="BrandID">1</column>
        <column name="BrandName">AX</column>
        <column name="CompanyInfo">FDC</column>
        <column name="Composition">Cap</column>
    </table>
    <table name="brands">
        <column name="BrandID">2</column>
        <column name="BrandName">UP</column>
        <column name="CompanyInfo">Tor</column>
        <column name="Composition">Asp</column>
    </table>
</tables>
```

And you'll need to adjust your JavaScript accordingly so select inside this wrapping node.

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify a single root node above the table nodes.

like

```
<root-node>
 <table name="brands">
        <column name="BrandID">1</column>
        <column name="BrandName">AX</column>
        <column name="CompanyInfo">FDC</column>
        <column name="Composition">Cap</column>
    </table>
    <table name="brands">
        <column name="BrandID">2</column>
        <column name="BrandName">UP</column>
        <column name="CompanyInfo">Tor</column>
        <column name="Composition">Asp</column>
    </table>
</root-node>
```

see the tutorial http://webhole.net/2009/12/16/how-to-read-xml-with-javascript/